# Facebook android SDK not working in release mode

Tags: android, react-native, oauth, facebook-login

I am using React Native FB SDK for logging in to my application.
On the iOS app everything works fine.
But on the Android app, it only works in debug mode, even though I added my development enviroment's debug key hash, and the signing keystore file's key hash.

I used this command to get the hash from SHA1:
`{SHA1} | xxd -r -p | openssl base64` and it worked fine for the debug key.
The app is not in google play store, test versions are distributed through AppCenter and the signing part is done manually with a keystore file.
Facebook app id and client token is added to string resources in build.gradle for different build flavors and referenced in the manifest.
In debug mode login works fine with both the facebook app or the webview, but in release mode nothing happens when I click on the login button.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to generate the release key hash using this command (For mac) and update it on a Facebook console.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Official Document Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/